# Adding variables together then running them through an If/else

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a form which takes the total ammout of products requested, adds them together and then based on the total amount of products, spits out a price.

This is what I've got so far:

```
 /* shipping total */
var imShipping = function(){
var emy = parseInt($('#user_inputEm').val());
    if (isNaN(emy)) emy = 0;
var pri = parseInt($('#user_inputprin').val());
    if (isNaN(pri)) pri = 0;
var glo = parseInt($('#user_inputglow').val());
    if (isNaN(glo)) glo = 0;
var deb = parseInt($('#user_inputdeb').val());
    if (isNaN(deb)) deb = 0;
var shitotal = parseInt($('thisValue').val(emy + pri + glo + deb));
    var sifunc = function(i){
    var any;
        if(i = 100){
         return any = 30;
        }else if(i = 200){
        return any = 50;
        }else{
        return any = 60;
        }
    };
return $('#shipQuote2').text(sifunc(shitotal));
}
```

here it is on jsfiddle.net
http://jsfiddle.net/4cUhp/20/

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#user_inputEm, #user_inputprin, #user_inputglow, #user_inputdeb').on('change', function() {
    $('#shipQuote2').text(function() {
        var emy = parseInt( ($('#user_inputEm').val()   || 0), 10),
            pri = parseInt( ($('#user_inputprin').val() || 0), 10),
            glo = parseInt( ($('#user_inputglow').val() || 0), 10),
            deb = parseInt( ($('#user_inputdeb').val()  || 0), 10),

            shitotal = emy + pri + glo + deb;

        if (shitotal = 100) { 
            return 30 
        }else if (shitotal = 200) { 
            return 50 
        }else{
            return 60;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks really good adeneo. I tried adding it but it only showed the first if statement "30" and wouldn't change when i entered a new value into the wristband fields.

Comment: @James - your if/else condition of course only works if the variable is exactly 100 or 200, otherwise it goes to the last else, and if the variable was say 99 or 3 it would always return 60. Also this only works once unless it's inside an event handler, like keyup, change etc. where this function runs each time the value of some element changes etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply adeneo. I understand how the if else statement works, the issue though is that for some reason it's returning 30 when it should be returning 60. Will the "shitotal" var update when i enter in a new value into any of the #user_input id's?

Comment: Not unless you have an event handler, like `$('#input_ID').on('change', function() { place code in answer here })`

Comment: I've entered it into an event handler .keyup() but still, it pumps out 30.

Comment: Then shitotal must be equal to 100, and it's really hard to figure out why that is ?

Comment: Yes. I can't understand why shitotal is = 100. I try entering in different values but shitotal doesn't change change.